# Typescript - remove null values from json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

i have a method in my service to save a date in my server, when this method sends the date to the server, it sends same fields as null in the json, how can i remove the fields with null value?

```
public create<T>(post: any): Observable<T> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    };
    return this.httpClient
        .post<T>(`${this.url}`, JSON.stringify(post), httpOptions)
        .pipe(catchError((err, source) => this.responseHandler.onCatch(err, source)));
}
```

the json send to server:

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "professionType":{
      "id": null
   },
   "comment": null,
   "organizationSpecialities":[
        {
         "speciality":{
            "id": null
         },
         "effective": 2,
         "effectiveDate":{
            "startDate": null,
            "endDate": "2019/12/01"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

the json i want to send:

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "organizationSpecialities":[
         "effective": 2,
         "effectiveDate":{
            "endDate": "2019/12/01"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: this will be pretty much to write, i think you need to go trought the Object.keys() recursively (when nested), and delete property that equals null

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can loop through the JSON and remove if the value is `null` or `Object.keys(o).length === 0`.

Following is the code.

```
cleanData(o) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(o) == "[object Array]") {
    for (let key = 0; key < o.length; key++) {
      this.cleanData(o[key]);
      if(Object.prototype.toString.call(o[key]) == "[object Object]") {
        if(Object.keys(o[key]).length === 0){
          o.splice(key, 1);
          key--;
        }
      }

    }
  }
  else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(o) == "[object Object]") {
    for (let key in o) {
      let value = this.cleanData(o[key]);
      if (value === null) {
        delete o[key];
      }
      if(Object.prototype.toString.call(o[key]) == "[object Object]") {
        if(Object.keys(o[key]).length === 0){
          delete o[key];
        }
      }
      if(Object.prototype.toString.call(o[key]) == "[object Array]") {
        if(o[key].length === 0){
          delete o[key];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return o;
}
```

For reference added [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbbmpc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) code.

Comment: Awesome answer, I deleted my answer and up voted this one.

Comment: when i put all the values that are in the list ' organizationSpecialities' to null, json looks like this:`"organizationSpecialities": [    {}  ]`, but in fact it should delete the the list

Comment: @AymenKanzari Updated the code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbbmpc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts and also in the answer.